# Can I get full list of likes for one media from Instagram Web without API?

Tags: web-scraping, instagram

I'm using `POST https://www.instagram.com/query/` and able to get many **comments** with a query:
`ig_shortcode(<media-code>){comments.last(300){count,nodes{id,created_at,text,user{id,profile_pic_url,username,follows{count},followed_by{count},biography,full_name,media{count},is_private,external_url,is_verified}},page_info}}`

But I can't do it for **likes**. I get error 400. I've tried the query:

`ig_shortcode(<media-code>){likes{count,nodes{user{id}}}}`

but the result is limited to 10.

There is offical `GET /media/media-id/likes` but it's too complicated to get the permission.

Are there other ways?

Answer (score 1):

I found an unoffical Instagram-API which does requests like official Instagram mobile client without any permissions: https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API

It has working method [$i->getMediaLikers($mediaId)](https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API/wiki#get-media-likers).

Comment: How do you use this method? and how do you traverse it?

Comment: I get all media published by specific user. Then, for each media I get the list of likers. Unfortunately, the list of likers has the limit - 100 users for each media without any pagination. I save each liker record using foreach in php `foreach ($response->users as $user)`.

Comment: you can only get 100 likers? is there still no way to retrieve the complete list of people who like a particular post?

Comment: @Anthony take a look at https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API/wiki#pagination May be it can help.

Comment: it wont work or at the very least its not feasible. ive already tried scraping it with selenium, but when a user has thousands or even tens of thousands of followers it takes too long with the appropriate delays so that you dont get timed out by IG :( smart on their part to use ajax, but its not very user friendly for users who do have thousands or tens of thousands or more users. thanks nonetheless